# graphviz Tree Layout

Tags: graphviz

I am using graphviz for the first time. I just need a tree layout so that all the childs are at the same level.

For example,
A->B
A->C
A->D

THEN B, C AND D SHOULD BE AT THE SAME LEVEL.

Following is the code I am using.

```
digraph unix {
    size="6,6";
    node [color=lightblue2, style=filled];

    "A:1000" -> "B:300";
    "A:1000" -> "C:300";
    "A:1000" -> "D:200";
    "B:300" -> "E:140";
    "B:300" -> "F:164";
    "B:300" -> "G:75";
    "C:300" -> "H:135";
    "C:300" -> "I:91";
    "D:200" -> "E:140";
    "D:200" -> "F:164";
    "D:200" -> "G:75";
    "E:140" -> "F:164";
    "E:140" -> "G:75";
    "F:164" -> "G:75";
    "G:75" -> "H:135";
    "H:135" -> "I:91";
}
```

How do I make sure that the childs are at the same level?

Comment: and tips to make the graph look cool will be great. I am presenting it to my friend.

Answer (score 10):

To get nodes on the same level, say "B:300" and "C:300", add the following line:

```
{rank=same; "B:300" "C:300"}
```

Comment: Thanks ars
But if I have to generate the graph dynamically, I won't know which nodes are siblings rite. 
I was thinking that if you write, A->B, A->C, A->D  .. graphviz would see that B,C and D are from same nodes hence need to be at same level.

Comment: If you're generating it dynamically, it might be simpler to add a `rank` line since you can determine the child nodes within your program.

Answer (score 3):

The graph you presented does not represent a tree, but a directed acyclic graph (In a tree there is only one distinct path between every pair of nodes). If your input would have been a tree, then just using `dot` would produce what you want. If you also want to add non-tree edges, like `"C:300" -> "H:135"` in your example, you could specify a lower weight for them, to make sure that `dot` doesn't try to optimize the layout with respect to these edges.

```
"C:300" -> "H:135" [weight=0];
"C:300" -> "I:91" [weight=0];
```

Note that these two edges become very long (and to `dot`, ugly) with this setting, and this is the reason why the node `"C:300"` is placed as it is in your original graph.

Comment: To make it short: this is not a tree as C => H => I but also C => I